# Does anyone know how to get a message from the Firebase in-app messaging server every time the app is launched?

Tags: firebase-in-app-messaging

Firebase In-App Messaging is designed to retrieve messages from the server only once a day, but I would like to retrieve Firebase In-App Messaging messages stored on the server at each app startup.
Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: I looked at this now too, and it seems that it's just not possible. Per campaign the most we can do seems to be "one impression a day per installment"; it seems that if I delete the app and install it, I can see the same message again. I assume this is because the install ID changes.